# Store a single character (tab, new line, any character) in User.config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to store and save back a single character in User.config (or App.config) file. Normal characters can be hold easily, but when it comes to special characters like `\t`, `\n` I cannot store them because VS2012 says it is not a character. I modify the User.config file with XML tags of `\t` which is `&#09;` it works! However, when it comes to save it again, it fails. When I assign `\t` character like this in code `Properties.Settings.Default.delim = '\t'` and call `Save` method, program only stores `\0` character. I cannot store XML equivalent string in code because it is a string, not a character and I'm trying to assign a string to a character.

Are there any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why not change your type to a string?

Comment: I need this to store a deliminator which should be character. It will then parse the data file. Yes I can store a string and get the first character, but this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the decimal ASCII code for the character by converting to an `int`, and convert it back to a `char` in your program.

e.g.

```
char charToSave = '\t';
int code = (int)charToSave;
SaveCharToUserConfig(code);

...

int code = GetCodeFromUserConfig(); 
char savedChar = (char)code;
```

Comment: Simple yet brilliant. Not exactly what I wanted but works. Thanks.

Comment: Now I see I need to use char[] or String to hold \r\n deliminators. However, again I'm stuck with the problem of saving them in to XML. I see any whitespace character is not kept while saving to User.config file. Is there any way rather than using a separate settings XML?

Comment: You could save a comma-delimited series of codes like "10,13", or an escape sequence like "\r\n". I suspect there is a more elegant solution though. You might want to post this as a separate question.