# Strongly typed setting of type 'char' in Visual Studio with special character as value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this VisualStudio solution with a project inside of it. I have added several strongly typed config settings, that are found in the Settings section of the app. However, when I try to add a char setting with special character as the actual value I get error similar to:

```
'\n' cannot be converted to an instance of type 'char'.
```

See attached screenshot below.

[image]

I have tried editting the underlying App.config xml file, but setting the value there to a special character such as **\n** or **\t**, simply resets the field to an empty character.

I need the said setting to be a configurable delimiter for one of my data parsers.

Is it possible to have strongly typed setting setting that is a special character? What is the workaround for the above error message?

Used Visual Studio version: VisualStudio Professional 2015 (.NET 4.7)

**Edit: The suggested duplicate question does not talk about app.settings or the limitaion imposed by Visual Studio at all. It is entirely different question**

Comment: Can you use the XML encoded values for `\n`? I _think_ it's `&#13;&#10;`

Comment: Its not working as "\" and "n" are considered separate characters here, together making a string. You can keep them in a `static` field/property if you wish to

Comment: What did you put in the App.config when you tried editing it as XML? `&#10;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# How to deal with Newline character, when moving strings to resources for Localization purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626767/c-sharp-how-to-deal-with-newline-character-when-moving-strings-to-resources-for)

Comment: I agree with Jon Hanna. I've just tried it myself and when you set the value `&#10;` directly in the App.Config file it does generate a new line. Visual studio's settings grid can't handle it, though, since a char is displayed as a single line and not a multi line.

Comment: The problem here is that VS does not preserve Whitespace characters when saving to app.config. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629807/store-a-single-character-tab-new-line-any-character-in-user-config-file See the accepted answer there or the related post here: http://kaskavalci.com/storing-whitespace-characters-in-app-config-file/ which might be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick & dirty workaround, you can store special characters in settings as integers. Then where you load the settings, you can typecast that int to a char. On saving the settings, you dont even need the typecast.